# white screen : 2.8" TFT LCD Screen Module: HY-280TFT

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, tft

i have a problem with my new  [2.8" TFT LCD Screen Module HY-280TFT](http://www.goodluckbuy.com/2-8-tft-lcd-screen-module-hy-280tft-w-sd-card-and-touch-screen.html).i connect it with an Arduino Uno board like this way: 
 [Connect HY-TFT280 to Arduino UNO](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/2.8%22TFT_LCD)

- LEDA -> 5V
- LEDK -> GND
- VCC -> 5V
- RD -> 3.3V
- GND -> GND
- DB0->DB5 to D8->D13
- DB6->A0
- DB7->A1
- DB10->DB17 to D0->D7
- RSET->A2
- CS->A3
- WR->A4
- RS->A5

i downloaded and installed the new [UTFT library](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=51). then i tested the example : *Arduino(AVR)->UTF_Demo_320x240* , but i always have a white screen.
In the code, i change

```
UTFT myGLCD(ITDB32WD,38,39,40,41); by UTFT myGLCD(ITDB32WD,A5,A4,A3,A2);
```

but i still have the white screen

please what can be the problem? thank you

Comment: Maybe the fact that the screen is an ILI9331 and not an ITDB32WD might have something to do with it. Looks like UTFT doesn't support that chip anyway. Maybe you should use the library they specifically link to on that Wiki page...?

Comment: thank you to reply me...the wiki page send me [link](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=39) . and there, they show us UTFT library